# Symfony bundle registration

Tags: symfony

I am maintaining an app that registers bundles in two different place:

1. In `app/AppKernel.php`, in the `$bundles` array
2. In `app/config/config.yml`, under the `bundles` key

ie, in `config.yml`:

```
    bundles:
    # Defaults (all currently registered bundles):
    - FrameworkBundle
    - SecurityBundle
    - TwigBundle
    - MonologBundle
    - SwiftmailerBundle
    - DoctrineBundle
    - AsseticBundle
    - FOSUserBundle
```

Registering in `AppKernel.php` was usual for me, but where/why is the registration in the `config.yml` file used?

Comment: I agree with your previous comment about the downvote thing! Never mind that! Moving on, maybe your application has some kind of custom functionality/bundle that reads `bundles` key and programatically registers the listed bundles. If it is the case then it has nothing to do with Symfony. You need to check your application to see if it is the case. I've never seen such built-in functionality in Symfony.

Comment: Could you please specify the Symfony version in your question?

Comment: @BentCoder - Hey mate, thanks for feedback (and the empathy!!!) , you answered my question, ie - seems custom, non-standard bulldung.  Happy holidays friend, peace to you and loved ones.

Comment: @Praveesh - Symfony version 2.7.50 - app/dev/debug

Comment: `bundles` key is probably some custom hacky/old-school logic. Use `AppKernel` for Symfony 3.2-, and bundle-less (configs only) for Symfony 3.3+.